# fwrite permissions for users of a webpage

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions, fwrite

I'm going to allow my users to make `iframe`d HTML pages on my site. They will input text including markup and I will create the .html file using `fwrite()`.

Are there reasons **not** to make the file permission for these .html files `0777`?

Obviously I don't want people executing javascript but other markup should be fine. Should I do `0766` instead then?

I'm not very familiar with permissions so general advice would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0777 is inappropriate for data files such as HTML. They should likely be set as 0644 (owner read+write, group/others read only).

Note that the executable bit on an HTML file has absolutely no bearing on what permissions it will have when loaded in a browser. For instance, Javascript will run just fine out of any HTML file, regardless of its permissions -- if you do not want to allow Javascript to run from these files, you will need to filter the content yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any reason not to make them 0777, besides being inappropriate from a semantic point of view?

Comment: Setting files to 0777 is a security risk -- it would allow other users on your server to write to them. With some file names, it may also inadvertently cause them to be executed as code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure, that they will upload **ONLY** html files - then it's fine.

Comment: would 766 prevent any javascript from executing? Are you saying 777 is fine? thanks

Comment: File permissions have nothing to do with javascript execution. Those permissions are for execution on the server.